# CORS policy problem in sub domain with laravel 8 angular 11

Tags: php, laravel, cors, angular11

I uploaded my Laravel project in example.domain.com and angular project in another subdomain, subdomain.domain.com, but I was faced with a CORS policy problem when logging into the system.

login.service.ts.

```
readonly baseURL = 'https://www.example.domain.com/api';

httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    })
  }

login(data:any){
    return this.http.post(this.baseURL + '/auth/login/', data ,this.httpOptions);
  }
```

api.php

```
Route::group([
    'middleware' => 'api',
    'prefix' => 'auth'

], function ($router) {
    Route::post('/login', [AuthController::class, 'login']);
});
```

AuthController.php

```
public function login(Request $request){
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:6',
        ]);
        // return response()->json($validator, 200);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json($validator->errors(), 422);
        }

        if (! $token = Auth::attempt($validator->validated())) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Either email or password is wrong.'], 401);
        }

        return $this->createNewToken($token);
    }
protected function createNewToken($token){
        return response()->json([
            'access_token' => $token,
            'token_type' => 'bearer',
            'expires_in' => auth()->factory()->getTTL() * 60,
            'user' => auth()->user()
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: The `/api` needs to be added to `baseUrl`.  see : `config/cros.php` . ` baseURL = 'https://www.example.domain.com/api/SOME';`

Comment: I added that but still not working.

Comment: Try this : make new middlware and follow this code  `return $next($request)->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS')->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers' , '*');`

Answer (score -1):

You can use laravel cors vendor for handling cors error.

https://github.com/fruitcake/laravel-cors